# Fetch all events From Office 365 Calendar

Tags: rest, calendar, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I need to fetch all events in an office 365 calendar.

Currently the GET request:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/events

returns only **10** events when we call the API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about first counting the number of events first and then making another call with $top query parameter?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/events?$count=true
```

The above api gives you the number of events as "@odata.count": 173 (for example) and then you make this call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/events?$top=173
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the documentation of this APIs? I need to get all the events in a specific month and year. Thanks in advance! :)

UPDATE: Already saw it. For anyone who is still searching, this might help you: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event

Comment: Might be obvious but if you need to do it in a single request, setting a ridiculously high number works as well : ?$top=10000