# Get O365 calendar events from multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, .net-7.0

In my app I have a Users-database. For each user in the database I need to get their O365 calendar events on a regular basis.

I have not done this before, so I followed [this exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-dotnet-core-access-user-events/1-introduction).
That doesn't seem hard to do, but it gives me only the events of one person.

Is it possible, when the user gives permission in the app, to store the access token in the Users-database and use it in the query for events instead of `Me`?

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927111/fetch-all-events-from-office-365-calendar) there's another approach(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/events?$top=173`) which I believe is just a HTTP-call that returns some data. Maybe I could use that approach (although it's 5 years old), but what header-values should I supply then?

Thanks.

Comment: using http call should have a request header `Authorization: Bearer {access token}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is Get O365 calendar events from multiple users. And I checked the exercise you shared, I noticed that you are trying to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which supports Application API permission.

[image]

So you can and you have to use the application API permission to realize your requirement. That's because the Graph API needs to have authorization to send the request, and you want to get other users' events, so the delegated API permission is not enough(delegated can be understood as, users sign in to get the authorization and the access token obtained should only be allowed to access user's own resource, so he can't access other users' event, while now we want to get other users resource instead of `.Me`).

Then consent API permission first, and then the code should be like below if the graph SDK you used is early than V5.x(because the practice is not based on the latest SDK)

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var calendarEvents = await graphClient
    .Users["userId"]//instead of .Me
    .CalendarView
    .Request(viewOptions)
    .Header("Prefer", $"outlook.timezone=\"{userTimeZone}\"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I get an "Unknown tenant" error even though I copied the "Object ID" from the AD. I guess I could figure that out. But:

1) can I get the TenantID based on the e-mailadress from the graph API?
2) as you say this is not the practice based on the latest SDK. Is this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider
3) will the http-call be according to current standard / best practise?

Comment: what I said `get other users resource instead of .Me` means we can use this graph api to get other users who are in the same tenant with the tenant of Me. So you don't need to get tenant based on the email address. And certainly, we can get tenant name from the email address if the email address is in the format of `user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`. If you want to use the lateset SDK, you only need to change the last line of the code snippet following the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

Comment: the http-call is certainly a good way to call the ms graph API, and when you want to send http call, you still need to obtain the access token. It's up to you to use graph SDK or send http call, both of them are OK, and I can't say which of them is the best practice.